# The game of coins.

Tags: logic, game-theory

Two players play the game:
There are two bowls, each of which can be fitted by some number of coins.

In the beginning the first player puts in the first bowl some natural number of coins of his choice. Then the second player, knowing how many coins the first put, puts in the second bowl some natural number of coins of his choice. Then, starting with the first player, each player makes one of the three possible moves:

1. Take any number of coins from the first bowl
2. Take any number of coins from the second bowl
3. Take the same number of coins from both bowls

Both players know how many coins lying in bowls at a time. The winner is the player, after which there will be no progress in the two bowls of coins.

The first player has put in the first bowl 100 coins. How many coins you need to put as the second player in the second bowl to win the game with the right playing of both players?

Comment: Where did you encounter this question?

Comment: Is the player who removes the last coin the winner or the loser? Can you choose to take no coins?

Comment: This question was asked and answered on this site two days ago. Please provide the source of the question. You can find our policy on contest problems [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy).

Comment: http://board.rt.mipt.ru/

and on the site of one bank there is post: "if you can solve it, you can work here". I solved it, but not sure that I am absolutely right

But I don't want to work in that bank. This is why I do not want to send them it.

I see that it breaks some rules of policy. Well, I can delete it and not learn right solution

Comment: @Dida Read up on the game called "Nim". This is a variation, but the same general principles to solve it should work.

Comment: @Dida: Many thanks for the honest response. As per the policy, one of the criteria for a question to be considered a contest question is that it's time-limited. ('If the "contest" has no definite duration, then we do not consider questions on it as contest questions for this discussion. This is to prevent indefinite lock-down of information.') I can't read Russian -- could you please let us know whether the request for submissions there is "active for a fixed, finite duration of time, with a definite start and end date"?

Comment: @joriki no. there is no time-limit for it.
In two words: "If you can solve it, you can think about work here. please send solutions to ***@gmail.com" 

But there is one moment: russian people who will guess to search this task on this site can easily find it and pass "the zero" condition of their interview at the bank. 

In this case it breaks policy rules.

And can you show me that question, which was asked two days ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(0,0)$ is a lost position.

$(0,x)$ and $(x,x)$, $x\ge1$, are won positions as we can move to $(0,0)$.

Therefore $(1,2)$ is lost.

Then $(1,x)$ and $(2,x)$, $x\ge 3$ are won (we can move to $(1,2)$ or equivalently $(2,1)$). Also, $(x,x+1)$, $x\ge 3$, are won.

In fact we have

**Lemma 1.** Let $d\ge0$ then there exists at most one $n$ such that $(n,n+d)$ is lost.

*Proof.* Assume $(n,n+d)$ and $(m,m+d)$ are lost positions with $0\le n<m$. As we can move from $(m,m+d)$ to $(n,n+d)$, we arrive at a contradiction. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $n\ge0$ then there exists at most one $m$ such that $(n,m)$ is lost.

*Proof.* Same argument. $\square$

An algorithm to list all lost positions is as follows: Assume we have found lost pairs $(a_0,b_0),\ldots, (a_{d-1},b_{d-1})$, where $b_k=a_k+k$.
Let $a_d=\min\Bbb N_0\setminus\{a_0,b_0,\ldots, a_{d-1},b_{d-1}\}$ and $b_d=a_d+d$.
I claim that $(a_d,b_d)$ is lost.
Indeed, $(a_d,x)$ is won for $0\le x<a_d$ per lemma 2, but also for $a_d\le x<b_d$ per lemma 1; likewise, $(x,b_d)$ and $(x,x+d)$ are won for $0\le x<a_d$ per lemma 2.

We thus find:
$$ (0,0),(1,2), (3,5), (4,7), (6,10), (8,13), (9,15), (11,18), (12,20), (14,23), (16,26), (17,28), (19,31), (21,34), (22,36), (24,39), (25,41), (27,44), (29,47), (30,49), (32,52), (33,54), (35,57), (37,60), (38,62), (40,65), (42,68), (43,70), (45,73), (46,75), (48,78), (50,81), (51,83), (53,86), (55,89), (56,91), (58,94), (59,96), (61,99), (63,102), (64,104), (66,107), (67,109), (69,112), (71,115), (72,117), (74,120), (76,123), (77,125), (79,128), (80,130), (82,133), (84,136), (85,138), (87,141), (88,143), (90,146), (92,149), (93,151), (95,154), (97,157), (98,159), (100,162),\ldots$$

So, the second player, who wants to present a lost position to the first player, must put 162 coins into the second bowl.

Comment: +1; but see also the duplicate :-) This is $(\lfloor62\phi\rfloor,\lfloor62\phi^2\rfloor)$.